# Eigenvalue with no eigenvector in $\mathbb{Q}^n$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I have a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $V$, and I have a linear operator $T$ on $V$. I have that $Tv=v$ only when $v=0$ for all $v\in V$, and $T^p=I$ for some prime $p$.

Now if I have any $v$ such that $Tv = \lambda v$ where $\lambda\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $T^p v = \lambda^p v = v \implies \lambda^p = 1$, whose only rational root is 1. But that means the only eigenvalue is 1 while the only eigenvector with eigenvalue 1 is the zero vector as stated, which makes no sense. What gives?

For more context, I have considered the $T$-cyclic subspace generated by some vector $v$, which is the span of $\{v, Tv, \dots, T^{p-1}v\}$. The characteristic polynomial of the matrix of $T$ restricted to this subspace with respect to the above basis is $x^p - 1 $, which again has only 1 as a root. I am trying to relate the degree of this polynomial to the dimension of $V$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just means that $T$ doesn't have any eigenvalues in $\Bbb{Q}$. There's no contradiction here. Matrices are guaranteed to have eigenvalues over $\Bbb{C}$ precisely because all polynomials have roots in $\Bbb{C}$, and it certainly is not the case that all polynomials have roots in $\Bbb{Q}$.

The (complex) eigenvalues of $T$ are primitive $p$th roots of unity.

Comment: So, it could be that some root of the characteristic polynomial is not an eigenvalue? That seems to go against its definition, of the "characterization".

Comment: Any root of the characteristic polynomial is an eigenvalue. But the characteristic polynomial need not have any roots! And what you've written constitutes a proof that, for your particular $T$, it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't quite get it. The polynomial has the factor $(x-1)$, iff it has 1 as a root, by the factor theorem. I can factor it as $x^p - 1 = (x-1)(x^{p-1}+\dots+x+1)$.

Comment: Indeed, which means that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ cannot actually be $x^p-1$.

Comment: The simplest interesting $T$ comes when $p=3$, and has matrix representation $\left(\begin{matrix}0 & -1 \\1 & -1\end{matrix}\right)$. Think about how your argument specializes to this $T$...

Comment: Oh, I see now! I had wrongly assumed that the matrix and hence the degree of the characteristic polynomial _had_ to be $p$, but that is obviously (in hindsight) not the case. So since $1$ is not an eigenvalue it must be that the other chunk $=0$, and is the correct characteristic polynomial for $T$.